# Add a white border on the right side of Shiny data table

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dt

I have a shiny web app that has a data table in it and I am looking to put a white border around it so it doesn't appear like it is cut off on the Right side of the page.

[image: This is what it looks like - click this link]

Here is the server code:

```
output$stats_table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    # Do not show the table when the page first loads
    # Wait until the user clicks "Plot" button
    if (input$plot_graph_button == 0)
    return()

   data <- summary_table
   data
}))
```

I found a parameter: `width = "80%"`, however, I have not gotten this to work.

Thank you in advance for any tips/help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out, for anyone who may encounter this same issue.

You cannot put:

```
width = "80%"
```

into the server code block, it actually has to be placed inside of the UI block otherwise the code will just get ignored.

Now looking back on this, it makes sense because the application looks to the UI code to render the space needed for the graph, hence why this is where you have to specify how much space it will take up.

My final code in the UI:

```
fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput("stats_table", width = "80%")
)
```

And the final result:

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtPNj.png)

Comment: I appreciate that this probably fixed the problem on your end, but people will get to this question on Google expecting an answer to the question you asked about border colors!